# Unable to access smb share on external USB on ubuntu 19.10 from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, samba

I've tested this on both EXT3 and NTFS USB drives (the same one, reformatted) - when I share a directory on an external USB drive as a smb share on a ubuntu 19.10 PC, I cannot access it using a PC running windows 10. I've tried setting a share from my home directory, and the windows 10 PC is able to access it.

Its mounted on `/media/geek/1 TB` and there's a few things using it. I'd like to have a directory inside it, lets call it "stuff" shared.

I've tried both mounting the drive itself through nautilus and fstab.

I'd like a simple, passwordless guest share

The fstab line was `#UUID=25454a67-7700-4e4f-a3af-538719d73ce5 /media/geek/1%40TB ext4 rw` It works locally with no issue.

When I share the folder either through nautilus' local file share option or by samba - and I'm trying with this very basic config file

```
[Stuff]
        comment = Torrent_Share
        path = "/media/geek/1 TB/Samba"
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
```

I've also tried renaming the mountpoint without a space.

On the windows end, the error I get is

[image]

On the Ubuntu side - looking at the log file for the windows client `/var/log/samba/log.aurora` shoes a rather cryptic error

```
geek@torrent-box:/media/geek$ tail /var/log/samba/log.aurora
[2019/12/14 18:00:50.380192,  0] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:448(change_to_user_internal)
  change_to_user_internal: chdir_current_service() failed!
[2019/12/14 18:00:50.380727,  0] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:448(change_to_user_internal)
  change_to_user_internal: chdir_current_service() failed!
[2019/12/14 18:00:50.382387,  0] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:448(change_to_user_internal)
  change_to_user_internal: chdir_current_service() failed!
[2019/12/14 18:00:50.383049,  0] ../../source3/smbd/uid.c:448(change_to_user_internal)
```

We can rule out permissions

```
geek@Stuff-box:~/Desktop$ stat share
  File: share
  Size: 4               Blocks: 2          IO Block: 512    directory
Device: 34h/52d Inode: 40498       Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/    geek)   Gid: ( 1000/    geek)
Access: 2019-12-14 18:00:46.352195708 +0800
Modify: 2019-12-14 18:00:46.324194693 +0800
Change: 2019-12-14 18:00:46.324194693 +0800
 Birth: -
```

This works

```
geek@Stuff-box:/media/geek/1 TB$ stat Stuff/
  File: Stuff/
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 52166657    Links: 6
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/    geek)   Gid: ( 1000/    geek)
Access: 2019-12-14 20:51:42.364000000 +0800
Modify: 2019-12-14 18:26:37.434393399 +0800
Change: 2019-12-14 18:26:37.434393399 +0800
 Birth: -
```

This does not.

I've tested the local file share/gui route on a directory on my home directory and it works fine. How do I actually get that folder sharable through some means?

Comment: Are you connecting to the share using your own account or as a "guest" / "anonymous" user?

Comment: as a guest. Mostly laziness, and I know for a fact that it works from /home/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a little interactive debugging on chat - apparently this might be an issue with the gnome file sharing system (which oddly isn't actually using samba).

using this manual samba config for the share worked

```
[Stuff]
comment = Stuff_Share
path = "/media/geek/1 TB/Stuff"
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
public = yes
force user = geek
```

Added it to the end of smb.conf and restarted samba and it worked.

I also had to start the samba service and enable it.